# Why can solve a,b,c=1,4,3 but a,b,c=2.5,-1.5,1.5 error, How to fix it

Tags: python, math

```
def run():
    c = input('Enter coefficients a, b, c :')
    a,b,c = c.split(',')
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    c = float(c)
    import math
    x1 = (-b -math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))
    x2 = (-b +math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))
    f =(math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))
    u = ('Can use quadratic formula:')
    if f >= 0 and a != 0 :
      print(u,'True')
    else :
      print(u,'False')
```

Write a program that finds the solution of the quadratic equation from the formula. x=−b±√b^2−4ac

by panel b^2−4ac≥0 and a≠0 and then show the results as shown in this example.

Comment: Are you saying that `a,b,c = c.split(',')` fails when the input is `2.5,1-5,15`? If so, you don't need the rest of the code to demonstrate the problem. Can you also post the full error message?

Comment: Check the value of `b^2-4ac` is postive before you sqrt it.

Comment: Because ... mathematics.  The roots for the quadratic equation for the case where a=2.5, b=-1.5, c=1.5 are complex numbers, and your code doesn't deal with that.  You stated the precondition b^2−4ac≥0 ... but that is violated for those coefficients.

Comment: sidenote: don't `import math` inside the `run` function. Put your imports at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

For the tuple 2.5, -1.5, 1.5, the discriminant is -12.25, so there are no real solutions.

The program fails because you attempt to extract the square root before checking whether the argument (the discriminant) is negative or not.

You can fix the program by rearranging the order in which the code checks for imaginary solutions, making sure that you evaluate the discriminant, and NOT its square root, before attempting to write a solution:

```
c = input('Enter coefficients a, b, c :')                                                  
    a,b,c = c.split(',')                                                                       
    a = float(a)                                                                               
    b = float(b)                                                                               
    c = float(c)                                                                               
    import math                                                                                
    f =b**2-4*a*c                                                                              
    u = ('Can use quadratic formula:')                                                         
    if f >= 0 and a != 0 :                                                                     
      print(u,'True')                                                                          
      x1 = (-b -math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))                                                         
      x2 = (-b +math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))                                                         
    else :                                                                                     
      print(u,'False')
```

I take this question is inspired by you learning to code, which is fine. From a numerical point of view, getting numerical solutions to the quadratic equation using this formula is *unstable* when `b**2` is very similar in value to `4*a*c` due to [round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error). Rationalizing the expressions for the roots helps with this issue. Finally, `import` statements are preferably located at the beginning of the script, and not in the middle of two code statements.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the coefficients a=2.5, b=-1.5, c=1.5, the quadratic equation produces complex roots, whereas coefficients a=1, b=4, c=3 yield real roots. Attempting to utilize math.sqrt() with complex numbers will result in a domain error, which shows as a ValueError.

I've provided a restructured version of the code below. This revised implementation outputs both roots only if they are real, 'False' otherwise. Also for formatting the import statement is moved to the top. The cmath.sqrt() function can return complex numbers, so you can just check to see if your result has imaginary components.

If desired you can use the complex number u to return the full complex roots.

Your answer may be affected by floating-point arithmetic errors, I've attached a link to learn more about how they can be reduced: [Fixing the Floating Point Arithmetic Precision Error in Python](https://python.plainenglish.io/floating-point-arithmetic-precision-error-in-python-decimal-comes-for-rescue-8803d1290601)

```
import cmath

def run():
    c = input('Enter coefficients a, b, c :')
    a,b,c map(complex, c.split(',')) # Map the comma-delimited input to 3 complex numbers
    u = cmath.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)
    print('Can the quadratic formula be used')
    if(u.imag == 0 and a != 0):
        print('True')
        print(f'Root 1: {((-b + u) / 2*a).real}')
        print(f'Root 2: {((-b - u) / 2*a).real}')
    else :
      print('False')
```